# HTML5 input - pattern with required="true" attribute still allows form submission

Tags: html, html-input

I have text box as below

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9|]{1,50}" title="Three letter country code" required="true">
```

When I submit the form without entering any value in the text box, empty string **""** gets submitted. I was hoping **required="true"** to catch it and throw an error. I think the combination of required and pattern attribute is causing it behave wrong.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Only `required` is required.

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9|]{1,50}" title="Three letter country code" required>
```

It's actually `required="required"` but you can ommit the second one and use the shorthand instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use required="required" insteed required="true"

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9|]{1,50}" title="Three letter country code" required="required">
```

Answer (score 0):

just add "/" in end of required

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9|]{1,50}" title="Three letter country code" required />
```